# How to group inner list data based on a key in outer list in c# linq

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

I have a class structure and data as follows:

```
   public class Company
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
public class Employee
{
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
}
  ObservableCollection<Company> list1 = new ObservableCollection<Company>
        { new Company { CompanyName = "com1",
                        Employees = new List<Employee>
                        { new Employee {EmployeeName = "Ron"},
                          new Employee { EmployeeName = "John" },
                          new Employee { EmployeeName = "David"  } } },
        new Company { CompanyName = "com2",
                        Employees = new List<Employee>
                        { new Employee {EmployeeName = "manuel"},
                          new Employee { EmployeeName = "smith" },
                          new Employee { EmployeeName = "rony"  } } },
        new Company { CompanyName = "com3",
                        Employees = new List<Employee>
                        { new Employee {EmployeeName = "kevin"},
                          new Employee { EmployeeName = "chacko" },
                          new Employee { EmployeeName = "willy"  } } }};
```

I want to group employeenames in Employee class based on outer company name in company class. How can i achieve this in linq.

Comment: Please describe the results that you would like to see. Each `Employee` is already attached to a `Company`, so the company object could be thought as employee's group. I imagine you are looking for something different, though, so please describe what it is.

Comment: Actually i am trying to implement grouping in xamarin forms. For that i need to group the inner list. Something like this http://motzcod.es/post/94643411707/enhancing-xamarinforms-listview-with-grouping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working, 
 I have added a class that inherits IEnumerable

```
    class GroupViewModel<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Items { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Id { get; private set; }
    public GroupViewModel(string name,string id, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Items = items;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.Items.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.Items.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Then i have grouped the list as below:

```
            var groupedList = from model in list1
                  group model by new { model.CompanyName,model.Id, model.Employees } into wordCollection
                  select new GroupViewModel<Employee>(wordCollection.Key.CompanyName, wordCollection.Key.Id, wordCollection.Key.Employees);
```